# Static route not found in aodv network

Tags: omnet++

In an AODV network, I hope that nodes can receive external messages and return a message at the same time. Therefore, I set the application layer app of a certain node to UdpEchoApp, and I refer to the method of example/emulation/pinger. Set up mrt for this node. You can see that the ip address of the eth0 port of this node is 192.168.2.1, and you can also see this static route in routingTable.
[image]

```
** Event #1457  t=4.898490315  Drone.host[19].ipv4.ip (Ipv4, id=927)  on Ext-UDP--1 (inet::Packet, id=2651)
INFO: Received (inet::Packet)Ext-UDP--1 (12 B) (inet::SequenceChunk) length = 12 B from upper layer.
INFO (Aodv)Drone.host[19].aodv: Finding route for source <unspec> with destination 192.168.2.2
INFO (Aodv)Drone.host[19].aodv: Missing route for destination 192.168.2.2
DETAIL (Aodv)Drone.host[19].aodv: Queuing datagram, source <unspec>, destination 192.168.2.2
INFO (Aodv)Drone.host[19].aodv: Starting route discovery with originator 192.168.2.1 and destination 192.168.2.2
INFO (Aodv)Drone.host[19].aodv: Sending a Route Request with target 192.168.2.2 and TTL= 2
```

But when sending a message to the external client of OMNeT++, it shows that the route of 192.168.2.2 cannot be found. Why is this and is there any solution. I am really distressed, hope to get help, thank you

This is my run.sh:

```
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
sudo ip addr add 192.168.2.2 dev veth1
sudo ip link set veth0 up
sudo ip link set veth1 up
sudo ethtool --offload veth0 tx off rx off
sudo ethtool --offload veth1 tx off rx off
sudo route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev veth1
sudo route add -net 145.236.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev veth1 gateway 192.168.2.1
```

ned code

```
package inet.examples.aodv.Drone;
import inet.common.scenario.ScenarioManager;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
import inet.node.aodv.AodvRouter;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.common.IntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;



network Drone
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=944.376,745.56");


    submodules:
        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,200;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.x.x'/> </config>");
                @display("p=100,100;is=s");
        }
        routingTableRecorder: RoutingTableRecorder {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,300;is=s");
        }
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,30");
        }
        scenarioManager: ScenarioManager {
            parameters:
                script = default(xml("<scenario/>"));
                @display("p=100,400;is=s");
        }
       host[numHosts]: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");   
            
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
}
```

ini file

```
[General]
network = Drone
scheduler-class = "inet::RealTimeScheduler"
#realtimescheduler-scaling = 120
**.fcsMode = "computed"
**.crcMode = "computed"

*.numHosts = 20
num-rngs = 3
**.mobility.rng-0 = 1   #随机生成mobility模块的初始位置或速度
**.wlan[*].mac.rng-0 = 2  #生成所有WLAN接口的MAC地址。

# channel physical parameters
**.wlan[*].typename = "AckingWirelessInterface"
**.wlan[*].bitrate = 2Mbps
**.wlan[*].mac.headerLength = 23B
**.wlan[*].radio.typename = "UnitDiskRadio"
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 96b
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.interferenceRange = 0m
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.detectionRange = 0m
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true

*.host[19].numEthInterfaces = 1
*.host[19].eth[0].typename = "ExtLowerEthernetInterface"
*.host[19].eth[0].device = "veth0"

# mobility
**.host[*].mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility"
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 600m
**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 600m

# ping app (host[0] pinged by others)
*.host[0].numApps = 2
*.host[0].app[0].typename = "PingApp"
*.host[0].app[0].startTime = uniform(1s,5s)
*.host[0].app[0].printPing = true
*.host[0].app[1].typename = "UdpSink"
*.host[0].app[1].localPort = 8000


*.host[19].ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "peer.mrt"

*.host[19].numApps=1
*.host[19].app[0].typename = "PingApp"
*.host[19].app[0].destAddr = "192.168.2.2"

# nic settings
**.wlan[*].bitrate = 2Mbps

# lifecycle
**.hasStatus = true

*.host[*].wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m

*.host[0].app[0].destAddr = "host[1](ipv4)"
```

peer.mrt

```
ifconfig:

# ethernet card (modelled by point-to-point link) 0 to router
name: eth0
    inet_addr: 192.168.2.1
    Mask: 255.255.255.255
    MTU: 1500
    Metric: 1
    POINTTOPOINT MULTICAST


ifconfigend.

route:
#Destination     Gateway          Genmask          Flags  Metric  Iface
0.0.0.0          *                0.0.0.0          G      0       eth0
192.168.2.2      *                255.255.255.255  H      1       eth0
routeend.
```

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you're asking, but remember that 192.168.x.x addresses are for internal use only.  They are only valid within the same subnet, and cannot be accessed from the outside.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. I am on the same computer, but 192.168.2.1 is the ip of a port in the OMNeT++ emulator, and 192.168.2.2 is the ip of the OMNeT++ external python client. In the example of the INET library of OMNeT++, the case of pinging 192.168.2.2 from the internal 192.168.2.1 is realized

Comment: @Jerzy D. Do you have any thoughts on this, or a workaround. Hope to get your help too, thanks

Comment: Could you provide versions of INET, OMNeT++ and OS as well as NED of your network and your omnetpp.ini?

Comment: ok, the version of inet is 4.4, and the version of omnet++ is 6.0.1. OS is Ubuntu20.04 I edited the source code of ned and ini on it. Sorry for the trouble, thank you again！@Jerzy D.

Comment: I think I found the cause of the problem. Because static routing cannot find route->getProtocolData() in AODV design, you need to manually use route->setProtocolData() to set.Also thanks to @Jerzy D. He helped me a lot.